# Stay on "CURLOPT_URL" for 60s

Tags: php

I'm using this code to test my Awstats with private proxies [4 ips]

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/"); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET,1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 5);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, trim($privateproxylist[$p]));
```

When I'm checking my stats I can see visits and refs but is there any option to make this script stay on CURLOPT_URL for 60s for each proxy?
Thanks

Comment: Do you know how awstats tracks visit time? Does it use an unload ajax handler? or does it get the visit time of "page 1" and visit time of "page 2" and subtract them to work out how long the user was on "page 1" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a webpage i found:

> Based on the time between a visitor's first and last document access
>   AWStats tries to calculate an average visit duration.

Therefore you need to wait 60s then make a request to the website again. As i don't know the internals of AWStats, you may need to use a different page url, but in theory, you should be able to just request the same url. Therefore its just a case of:

```
// 1. Make your curl request to URL
// 2. Wait 60s
sleep(60);
// 3. Make the curl request again 
// 4. Change proxy and go back to step 1
```

Of course this is syncronous, so you will have the script running for a minimum of 4 minutes (based on 4 proxy ips), so dont forget to set the execution time limit of your php script to unlimited (or very high).

You may also need to set the "cookiejar" config on the curl resource, as awstats MAY use a session cookie or something like that, to identify visitors. So a cookiejar text file will need to be set, so the session cookie can be stored and then resent on the second request. Don't forget to clear the cookie file (or just set a new text file in the options) before using a new proxy ip.